# Why is FindRoot throwing a "singular Jacobian" error when function has small values?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, special-functions, singularity

Running the code:

```
FindRoot[PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] == 10^-30, {x, 10}]
```

Gives me the error:

```
FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x} = {27.0291}.
                 Try perturbing the initial point(s).
```

As far as I can tell, the Jacobian (derivative?) is not singular; perhaps something is going wrong because some very small values are involved?

Mathematica also returns the solution `x → 27.0291`, which is just wrong. What's the issue here and how can I avoid it?

**Update**

The above equation is unsolvable as is, because it should have a negative sign in front. With the negative sign, the exact same issue occurs:

```
FindRoot[-PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] == 10^-30, {x, 10}]

>> FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x} = {27.0291}.
                  Try perturbing the initial point(s).

   {x -> 27.0291}
```

Comment: I agree it is confusing. help says `This message is generated when the derivatives of the first argument in FindRoot are singular at the indicated point.`  At first I thought the indicated point means the starting root finding point, which is 10 in your case. But it is be the ending point (i.e. root found) (as message says). Try this `root = x /. 
   FindRoot[PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] == 10^-30, {x, 10}];
der = D[-E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2]), x];
(der /. x -> root) // Chop` which gives `zero`. So derivative of the function is `zero` at the root found (not at the starting point !)

Comment: `Mathematica also returns the solution x → 27.0291, which is just wrong` can you please explain why is this wrong? A quick plot indicates it seems to be correct.

Comment: When I plot your `PolyLog` function, it is negative.  It can't be equal to `10^-30`.  You can increase the `WorkingPrecision`, but you still need a solvable equation.

Comment: 1. Expressing the Fermi-Dirac integral in terms of the polylogarithm is usually not numerically advisable, since evaluations can get unstable. 2. Are you sure your polylogarithm can become positive? Plotting `PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])]` indicates that this function is always negative for all real `x`.

Comment: @Nasser ```-PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + 27.0291^2])]``` returns ```8.13645*10^-17```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to have a negative sign in front of the ```PolyLog``` function. When included, the same issue occurs.

Comment: @Nasser that's a good point about the derivative being zero, not infinite. But in fact the derivative is *not* zero, it's just very small. Is there a trick to get around this?

Comment: @J.M. I was thinking that writing out the integral in a closed form would save computational effort compared to numeric integration—is there a different approach that would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we examine the Jacobian, we can see numerical problem:

```
D[-PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])], x]
(*  -(x Log[1 + E^(-10 - Sqrt[1 + x^2])])/Sqrt[1 + x^2]  *)
```

The argument `1 + E^(-10 - Sqrt[1 + x^2])` of `Log` will be equal to `1` and the Jacobian equal to zero, when `0 < E^(-10 - Sqrt[1 + x^2]) < $MachineEpsilon`.  This happens for all `x > 26.0244`:

```
FindRoot[E^(-10 - Sqrt[1 + x^2]) == $MachineEpsilon, {x, 1}]
(*  {x -> 26.0244}  *)
```

Therefore the root, which is about `59`, cannot be found.

A workaround is to use `` Internal`Log1p[x] ``, which is equal to `Log[1 + x]` but avoids computing `1+x`:

```
Block[{Log = Internal`Log1p[-1 + #] &},
 FindRoot[-PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] == 10^-30, {x, 10}]
 ]
(*  {x -> 59.0691}  *)
```

Another, simpler way is to use arbitrary precision:

```
FindRoot[-PolyLog[2, -E^-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] == 10^-30, {x, 10}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 16] 
(*  {x -> 59.06908873204437}  *)
```

Note we don't have to use a high precision because the precision of `` 1 + 1.`16*^-30 `` is `46` by the rules of arbitrary precision.  Therefore the Jacobian will be calculated accurately.

Comment: Thanks. Both answers were good, but I like that this one pointed out the simple fix of increasing ```WorkingPrecision```.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment, this is one of those situations where a closed form is ***not*** helpful. In this case, forcing the [Fermi-Dirac integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral) to be expressed as the polylogarithm of an exponential results in numerical grief.

Thus, by instead applying the formula in item 4 of [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Integral_representations) (which can be derived using the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula)), we have the following computation:

```
prec = 50;
tmp[x_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[Csch[π u] Sin[2 ArcTan[u] + u (10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])]/(1 + u^2),
                              {u, 0, ∞}, Method -> "DoubleExponential",
                              WorkingPrecision -> (prec - 5)]

With[{ε = 1*^-30},
     FindRoot[tmp[x] == ε Exp[10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2]] - 1/2,
              {x, 50, 60}, WorkingPrecision -> prec]]
   {x -> 59.069088732044366955570311882437432292701716044411}

-PolyLog[2, -Exp[-(10 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])]] /. First[%]
   1.000000000000000000000000000000000000003352846600*^-30

% - 1*^-30
   3.352846600*^-69
```

Note the [use of `NumericQ[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037) in the definition for `tmp[]`, as well as the use of a higher `WorkingPrecision` setting in `FindRoot[]` than in `NIntegrate[]`.